# Using logical AND query in Kibana and C# NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I am trying to implement a simple query in Kibana and then in C# NEST. I am from a SQL background and am struggling to find documentation to perform a relatively simple SQL query in Elasticsearch. The query I am trying to implement is effectively......

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE logdate > STR_TO_DATE('2020-02-01 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
AND logdate < STR_TO_DATE('2020-02-03 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
AND username = 'user01'
```

I can do them as individual kibana queries....

```
GET auditlog/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "logdate": {
        "gt": "2020-02-01T23:59:59",
        "lt": "2020-02-03T00:00:00"
      }
    }
  }
}

GET table/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "username": "user01"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try and combine them into one query I get a "parsing_exception" error...

```
GET auditlog/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "username": "user01"
          },
          "range": {
            "logdate": {
              "gt": "2020-02-01T23:59:59",
              "lt": "2020-02-03T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have looked at the Elasticsearch documentation and can't seem to find the answer so any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
GET auditlog/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "username": "user01"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "logdate": {
              "gt": "2020-02-01T23:59:59",
              "lt": "2020-02-03T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried converting to NEST but have errors as string to double conversion on dates, then cannot convert lambda expressions to types 'Nest.ISearchRequest' 
 & 'Nest.QueryContainer[]

```
Client.SearchAsync<AuditRecord>(s => s
.From(0)
.Take(10)
.Query(q => q
.Bool(b => b
.Must(m => m
.Range(r => r
.Field("Timestamp")
.GreaterThan("2017-03-07T13:30:00")
.LessThan("2017-03-07T13:40:00")
)
)
.MatchPhrase(mp => mp   
.Field("Action")
.Query("Week No: 30")
)                                    
)
)).Result.Documents.ToList();
```

Comment: @adig14 Use `.DateRange()` instead of `.Range()`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-range-query-usage.html